# Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction has finished

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I am trying to update an entry in my simple to do app with indexedDB, however I am getting **Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction has finished.**

I can't seem to figure out why it won't finish the transaction, I tried the debugger and it stops at this line: `var updateNameRequest = tasksStore.put( requestForItem.result.name, Number(requestForItem.result.id))` Please see the snippet I included below. For additional context creating, reading, and deleting work just fine it's just updating data that I'm having trouble with

I also tried to implement the openCursor technique which I got from Mozilla which I commented out since it also doesn't work (I get the same behavior) [Check out my repo I know it's still very messy :(](https://github.com/ancheta98/PWA-IndexedDB/tree/master/quickStartIndexedDB)

```
const request = window.indexedDB.open("toDoList", 2);
var db;

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
  console.log("check out some data about our opened db: ", request.result);
  db = event.target.result; // result of opening the indexedDB instance "toDoList"
  getTasks(); //just a function to retrieve data
};

$(document).on("click", ".editBtn", function () {
  var transaction = db.transaction("tasks", "readwrite");
  var tasksStore = transaction.objectStore("tasks");
  console.log(tasksStore);
  let taskId = $(this).attr("idNo");

  var requestForItem = tasksStore.get(Number(taskId));
  requestForItem.onsuccess = function () {
    // console.log(requestForItem.result)
    var oldData = requestForItem.result;
    // prepopulate the input
    $(".editInput").val(requestForItem.result.name);

    $(".saveBtn").click(function () {
      requestForItem.result.name = $(".editInput").val().trim()
      console.log( requestForItem.result)
      var updateNameRequest = tasksStore.put( requestForItem.result.name, Number(requestForItem.result.id))
      console.log("-------------", updateNameRequest.transaction) // doesn't get to this line
      updateNameRequest.onerror = function() {
        console.log("something went wrong")
        console.log(updateNameRequest.error)
      };
      updateNameRequest.onsuccess = function() {
        console.log("here")
        $(".editInput").val("")
        getTasks();
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async operations inside indexeddb cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888068/async-operations-inside-indexeddb-cursor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indexed DB transactions auto-commit when all requests have been completed and no further requests were made before control returns to the event loop. Put another way - you can make new requests in the success or error callback from a previous request, but not in other asynchronous callbacks such as event handlers.

You need to start a new transaction within the click handler, because any previous transaction will have autocommitted.

Comment: Oh my goodness you saved me a huge headache!! Thank you so much I just edited it and now my code is working.

Alexa play Sweet Victory