# variable updated inside ".then" in fetch not reflected outside in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, indexeddb

I tried updating IndexedDB data inside ".then" in fetch but that doesn't work inside event handlers as I got to know that from this post [post-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296252/failed-to-execute-put-on-idbobjectstore-the-transaction-has-finished). Updating the IndexedDB data outside the ".then" is working.
So I created a boolean variable and tried updating it inside the ".then" and thought of updating the IndexedDB data outside but the boolean value is not getting updated inside the ".then".

```
.then(() =>{
        data_inserted = true ;
      })
```

Now outside the ".then"

```
console.log(data_inserted); // value is false
      if ( data_inserted === true )
      {
// update IndexedDB code
      }
```

I saw this post [post-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and I'm not sure how to do a callback function as they did for my code.

Kindly help me in updating the boolean variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more of the surrounding code?  Specifically, where are you declaring "data_inserted"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is a lack of understanding of async code.

The async code, `then`, will happen AFTER the code that follows it.  Note:

```
let foo = "bar"
someFunctionThatTakesOneSecond()
    .then((res) => {
        foo = "baz"
        console.log("then: ", foo); 
    })
console.log("there: ", foo)
```

Will output:

```
 there: bar
 then: baz
```

Why?   Because the code in the 'then' won't run until after `someFunctionThatTakesOneSecond" completes and the promise is fulfilled.  But the code after the async block will run synchronously (ie: right away).

You may wish to use the async/await pattern instead - `await` stops further execution until the async function returns.

So:

```
let foo = "bar"
await someFunctionThatTakesOneSecond()
foo = "baz"
console.log("then: ", foo); 
console.log("there: ", foo)
```

Would output:

```
 then: baz
 there: baz
```

Read more on async/await and asynchronous JavaScript here: https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-asynchronous-javascript/